# ID Generation for Sharded Database (Azure Federated Database)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, sharding

I have been looking for some articles or guidence on best practice for id generation (for the federated/primary key) for Azure Federated databases and haven't found anything compelling.  Federated tables don't support identity columns, so it seems to me that the only practical type of id is a GUID, as trying to centrally create and use a BigInt creates a single point of failure in the app.  My chief concern is the performance implications of using GUIDs over BigInts (particularly for indexing the tables).

Is there any recommended/best practice (or existing libraries) to create unique BigInts for a distributed system (or should I not worry about the performance implications of using GUIDs?).

[Update]

Having read a lot more about this since posting the question, it seems to me that key generation will be a problem in Azure.  As per the this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/06/20/id-generation-in-federations-identity-sequences-and-guids-uniqueidentifier.aspx) post from Microsoft, it is recommended to use GUIDs as Federated key.  However they fail to mention that all indexes (including clustered indexes) on Federated tables have to contain the federated key.  This means that all these indexes will contain a GUID, which is going to kill insert performance.

The alternative seems to be using a centeralized key generation service (as mentioned by Simon below) which has its own drawbacks in terms of being a potential bottle neck and central point of failure.

I would have thought there would have been more guidence on this from Microsoft as surely this is an issue that everyone creating federated tables will face!

On balance I have decided to go with a centeralized key generation service, but it does concern me a little bit.  If anyone has some magic technique I would love to hear it (or let me know if I am missing something obvious) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create sequences in the application using a variety of techniques, but they are not straightforward because of the distributed nature. One that is quite good is using [blob storage and preconditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309174.aspx).

Depending on your project schedule you may want to use the [SQL 2012 SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and put all your sequences in a small non-federated database. SEQUENCE is not available *yet* on SQL Azure.

Answer (score 2):

When you think about your federation key it is important to think about a key that will actually cause a good distribution across federation members, so in many cases a generated id is not a good idea.
For example - partitioning on order id will mean that all the latest orders are in the latest federation member, and is likely to be the one most users are acting on, so the benefits of federation will be greatly reduced, partitioning on country/customer id/etc is more likely to achieve the scalability benefits federation is designed to bring.

When it comes to a row's unique identity you need to consider that entities will be stored accross different databases and for that reason identity or sequence generations are not available, check out Cihan Biyikoglu [blog post on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/06/20/id-generation-in-federations-identity-sequences-and-guids-uniqueidentifier.aspx) - his recommendation is to either use uniqueidentifier or datetimeoffset

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I always using GUID for the federation key, as I don't think it causes massive performance problem. Maybe my project is not that huge, but it does works to me. So my answer to your first question is 'yes'.

Your next question, I'm thinking about to have an ID Generator service there, exactly as that you thought, but yes it could be a bottleneck. I was thinking if we can have an ID pool, which utilizes some distribution cache to store the IDs that generated by this service. So that use anyone wants an ID it will retrieved from the pool, rather than generating on demand. So the ID Generator will continue pushing IDs in that pool and the consumers will pop an ID from it. That might be helpful, but again, I've never implemented in this way so I may not be able to say if it's the best practice or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The one negative of using a GUID as a primary key is that if the table is clustered on the primary key, it would cause substantial page splits on inserts. This is because good GUIDs are not generated in chronologically order so as to be hard to guess.

Azure SQL tables **do** need a clustered index. My suggestion is to have a clustered index on a range based value (like datetime) and use a **non-clustered** index for the primary key, which would be the GUID.

Comment: Hi @Lucifure - Unfortunately that won't work, as the federated key has to be included in any clustered indexes...that is a limitation of Azure Federated tables.

Comment: @Mike, would not adding the primary key to the clustered index work?
So, for example, clustered index is datetime+PK and the PK is by itself another index.

Comment: If I understand what you are suggesting I don't think that will work, as another limitation is that the federated key must be included in any unique indexes (as well as clustered indexes).  As the PK by itself would be another unique index I don't see any way to effectively use GUIDs.  There is more detail about the limitations here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597469.aspx