# Sequential Id in Azure SQL Federation

Tags: sql-server, sequence, azure-sql-database, sharding, federation

I use Azure SQL federation to store users. As I read in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/06/20/id-generation-in-federations-identity-sequences-and-guids-uniqueidentifier.aspx) article, the best way to generate distributed federation key is to use GUID. I think show GUIDs to user isn’t human friendly, so I would like users also have ids like 1,2,3,4,5 and so on. Now I’m planning to have one table in federation root database to store sequential ids and federation keys. 
Or is there better approach to achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identity alternative for SQL Azure Federation : are Azure Queues or Service Bus Queues a good choice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761783/identity-alternative-for-sql-azure-federation-are-azure-queues-or-service-bus)

Comment: You will shoot yourself in the foot if you take this approach. Better not use federations at all if think that direction. Check the very same question asked a while ago.